# Python griddata — Grid Not Accepting Path Argument

Tags: python

I am following the instructions on this website to read a file in the DX Format: [griddataformats.readthedocs.io](https://griddataformats.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gridData/formats/OpenDX.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20OpenDX%20files%20from%20other%20software,produced%20by%20common%20visualization%20programs%20%28VMD%2C%20PyMOL%2C%20Chimera%29)

However, when I run:

```
from griddata import Grid
g = Grid("INSERT PATH")
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

EDIT: The script appears to run fine occasionally, but on some runs returns this error. How do you stop this from happening?

Comment: I GUESS that the  Grid module level method instantiates a grid object and you need to call some method of the object to read the data, and in general reading the documentation is a good idea.

Comment: @gboffi Just want to update that it doesn't cause this error on every run. It's quite strange.

Comment: I can't afford to have the library not run correctly on occasional runs.

Comment: When the line of code you posted is executed, the TypeError will always be raised. If in some runs you have no errors, it simply means that that line of code is not executed. That's all from me, it's bed time...

Comment: I am running a file with just this line above, it occasionally errors and occasionally gives the expected output.